# vuedraggable background makes div not draggable

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, computed-properties, vuedraggable

I have vuedraggable added to a mobile game I am making where people can unscramble sentences. It has worked great up until this point. I recently added a background image to my draggable elements from a sprite sheet but now my draggable elements are no longer draggable. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this behavior is occurring?

here is my Vue template

```
<template>
  <div :key="verse" class="center">
    <h2 v-if="message !== ''">{{ message }}</h2>
    <div id="scriptureBackground">
      <draggable
        v-model="words"
        class="drag-list"
        :list="words"
        animation="200"
        ghost-class="moving-card"
      >
        <div
          v-for="(value, index) in words"
          :key="index"
          @mousedown="playPress"
          class="drag-word"
          :style="stoneWord"
        >
          {{ value }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>
      <p :verse="verse" slot="footer" class="verse">- {{ verse }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

stoneWord is a computed

```
    stoneWord: function() {
      return {
        background: `url(${this.icons}) -2722px -60px`,
        "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
        width: "885px",
        height: "400px",
        zoom: `0.1`,
        "-moz-transform": `scale(0.1)`,
        display: "flex",
        "justify-content": "center",
        "align-items": "center",
        "font-size": `20vw`,
        "margin": "10px",
      };
    },
```

Comment: Why not put that CSS into an actual CSS block instead of returning it in a javascript function? It doesn't look at all dynamic. You should be able to attach it to `.drag-word{...}` then the styling and drag functions are completely separate. That will at least allow you to debug it more easily.

Comment: Eventually the font size and the zoom will be dynamic. I will add it to the drag-word class and let you know what I find

Comment: Yeah, I think it's some issue parsing the CSS in javascript. Remember it doesn't need to be an all or nothing. Put the common styles in CSS and then let javascript inline the dynamic stuff.

Comment: From what I've found the issue is with how vuedraggable interacts with the zoom or the -moz-transform css properties. Your suggestions did help me debug it. thanks for the info on best practices and your time!

Comment: That would make sense as zoom/transform will impact how the size and position of an element are calculated. Glad you got a thread to pull! Good luck.